# "because" after "since"

Tags: grammar

Can "because" come after "since?"

Here's an example sentence.

> I don't like when you do that, because
>   since it makes you look weird, it also
>   makes me look weird when I'm with you.

Is there anything grammatically wrong with that sentence? "Since" after "because" works here, right?

Comment: In one of those contrived sentences such as 
"Because cannot be used after **since, because** it does not look right"

Comment: Note that you may want to say ["I don't like *it* when ..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/i-hate-when-vs-i-hate-it-when), depending on the level of formality and the location of your intended audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically fine, but it does sound awkward. To me it’s not the sequence *because since* so much as the multiple conditionals. It reminds me of sentences like *I went, but I left my hat behind, but that’s OK.* I would rephrase it.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> I don't like when you do that. It makes you look weird, and it also makes me look weird when I'm with you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like when you do that. It makes you look weird, which makes *me* look weird.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, "because" should be followed by a comma instead of being preceded by one.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically fine but, as most have already said, would benefit from rewording.

I would suggest employing a semi-colon between the parts, as shown below:

I don't like when you do that; since it makes you look weird, it also makes me look weird when I'm with you.