# Dropping "it" in America

Tags: american-english, objects, transitive-verbs, dummy-it

Before I embraced descriptive grammar it would really grind my gears when I heard, usually from someone with a US American accent, phrases like "I hate when that happens". "Hate is a transitive verb!" I would yell.

(To my knowledge it's not normal to drop *it* in "UK English".)

However, these days I'm more mellow. My left eye twitches but I pinch myself and remember that language evolves.

Which leads me to my questions. I've seen the dummy object eroded from phrases involving *love*

- > I love when you give me a kiss
  >   — Ordinary Alphabet: Poems by an ordinary girl, p. 107, Michelle McNair, Bloomington (Indiana): Author House.
- > I love when she screams to the audience
  >   — Tell Them That I Love Them: A Story of Grace and Redemption, p. 206, Angela Sanders, Euclid (Ohio): Sandstorm Publishing.

and *hate*

- > I hate when that happens
  >   — Letters to My Sister, p. 61, Maxine Oliveres, Pennsylvania (Pittsburgh): Red Lead Press
- > I hate when people try to take advantage of me
  >   — If You Could See What I See, p. 93, Cathy Limb, New York (New York): Kensington Publishing Crop.

in "American English". Is *it* only dropped before a conjunction, or is it OK to drop *it* at other times? Is it only *love* and *hate* where *it* gets dropped, or are there other verbs that lose the dummy pronoun?

Comment: I can't drop the *it* there myself. It sounds weird to me.

Comment: Related:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134005/i-like-it-that-vs-i-like-that

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/i-hate-when-vs-i-hate-it-when

Comment: That doesn't seem like a duplicate. I'm asking when it's permitted to drop *it*, that asks if it's correct or just common usage (and some unrelated stuff).

Comment: Would you say, for example, *I remember it when he arrived* or *I understand it why she left*? I always felt the *it* was superfluous in such constructions from a very early age (1980s Southern California), and having trained myself not to say it, loathed [it] when others did say it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure about this question now. I think I've noticed a weirdness in UK English, not American English.

Comment: @choster: But those should be *dependent questions*: a separate category that normally does not have an antecedent. It's quite different from *\*I hate when*: the verb *hate* is normally connected with a subordinate clause using *that*, not *when* as is possible with dependent questions.

Comment: I'm guessing based on [this ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hate+it+when%2Chate+when&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chate%20it%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chate%20when%3B%2Cc0) that including the "it" is a pretty recent phenomenon.  So maybe the question is: When did it become more idiomatic to write "I love it when" or "I hate it when" whereas other transitive verbs seem *not* to use "it."

Comment: I found a citation showing this usage isn't strictly American: George Bernard Shaw, 1883: *"I never said you had no heart," protested Jane ; " but I hate when you speak like a book."* - An Unsocial Socialist.

Comment: It's clearly not just _love_ and _hate_ as such: at the very least, any verb that has a similar meaning to one of those two (loathe, detest, adore, like, abhor, etc.) function similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"I hate when that happens"** is a transitive usage of *hate*. The object is the clause "when that happens".

Compare "I know he is lying", where "he is lying" is the object of the transitive *know*. Also "People say Roberta Flack is a great singer", where "Roberta Flack is a great singer" is the object of the transitive *say*.

Comment: Perhaps I should reverse the question, and ask why we don't turn "when that happens" into an object in the UK. Although I suppose that's unanswerable.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Yeah, "why" questions like that are hard to answer. All we can say is, the usage seems to differ.

Comment: "I know he is lying" is a (perfectly acceptable) example of dropping "that".

Answer (score 0):

Speaking solely from my own experience of hearing it in AmE, this is a somewhat perverse usage that entered my awareness sometime in the mid-1980s. It was used as a kind of Zeitgeist meme, and with the same kind of relish pop culture aficionados use for that sort of utterance, and I recall thinking it must have been from some sort of TV show (like the "dy-no-mite!" meme [originated by actor Jimmie Walker on an American television show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmie_Walker)).

Again, to the best of my recollection it was used precisely *because* it was so perverse sounding. People would say it for emphasis (and for the nudge of recognition it engendered in the listener) because that hint (okay, *more* than a hint) of discordance, as well as for its tag-like quality. Google NGrams shows its use in print peaking around the early '90s, and its frequency even at that peak was still [only around 75% that of "I hate **it** when that happens."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+hate+when+that%2CI+hate+it+when+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20hate%20when%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20hate%20it%20when%20that%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: George Bernard Shaw, 1883: *"I never said you had no heart," protested Jane ; " but I hate when you speak like a book."* is an early non-American (though non-English) example.